# How to set IXMLHTTPRequest.Timeout in C++ MSXML 6.0?

Tags: c++, xmlhttprequest, msxml6

I don't see timeout property at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760305(v=vs.85).aspx

This causes send method to hang sometimes (timeout seems to be infinite).

Comment: That's a bug in MSXML and is not specific to the C++ interface (same will happen via JavaScript and VBScript). Set your own timer and call `abort()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. However, abort()? Do you mean that abort() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx ? It stops the entire process. Pretty rough for me as the entire app gets closed..